# How to create a variable from an url?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

My URL takes a variable "payment_option" like this:

```py
 path('payment/<payment_option>/', PaymentView.as_view(), name='payment')
```

I want to show that variable in the template rendered out by PaymentView.

The problem is that "payment_option" isn't a paramenter in my models (like pk or a slug) but his value is got from a form handled by another view.

```py
class CheckoutView(View):
  [...]
  def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CheckoutForm(self.request.POST or None)
        [...]
        payment_option = form.cleaned_data.get('payment_option')

        if payment_option == 'S':
          return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='stripe')
        elif payment_option == 'P':
          return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='paypal')
```

Hope my explanation was as clear a possible, I'm new to Django so any hint or suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: You can obtain the parameter with `self.kwargs['payment_option']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the urls variables from kwargs.

```
class CheckoutView(View):
    [...]
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        payment_option = kwargs.get('payment_option',None)
        form = CheckoutForm(self.request.POST or None)
        [...]
        #payment_option = form.cleaned_data.get('payment_option')

        if payment_option == 'S':
            return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='stripe')
        elif payment_option == 'P':
            return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='paypal')
```

Comment: You will have to send it to the form manually if the form needs it